Almost sure convergence of a double sum of gaussian RVs
My goal is to show that
$$
\operatorname{P}\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \left\{n^{-3/2}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\sum_{j = 1\atop j \neq i}^{n}\left[x_{i}^{2} - 1\right]x_{j} \right\} = 0\right) = 1
$$
Where sequence $x_{i}$ is i.i.d. normally with zero mean and $1$ variance. It is easy to show that, for
$$
Y_{n} \equiv n^{-3/2}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\sum_{j = 1\atop j\neq i}^{n}}\left(x_{i}^{2} - 1\right)x_{j}
$$

$\mathbb{E}\left[Y_{n}\right] = 0$ and $\operatorname{var}\left[Y_{n}\right] \approx n^{-1}$. So I know that it converges in probability, but due to $n^{-1}$ scaling for the variance I can not use the Borel-Cantelli lemma.
I asked a professor and they told me that since I have convergence in probability I could try showing that the sequence "didn't wiggle too
much" by using Kolmogorov's inequality and "Martingale stuff".
However I couldn't really figure out how to apply Kolmogorov's inequality since it seems to be defined for only sums of i.i.d. variables.

If you could point me towards a possible path forward I'd be very grateful.

Since all the variables are $N(0,1)$, you can try to compute $E[Y_n^3]$ or $E[Y_n^4]$. I believe that you gonna have something bigger than order $1/n$, say $1/n^\alpha$ then from this you have $ \sum_{n = 1}^ \infty E[ | Y_n |^3] < + \infty $ which implies $Y_n \rightarrow 0$ a.s (use Borel Cantelli).

@LNT yeah looks like it. I don't see how I would use Doob's seeing that $Y_n$ in my definition is not any sort of martingale. $|Y_n|$ from Drew Brady's definition would be a submartingale but that doesn't really give me anything useful if plugged into Doob's inequality and $|Y_n n^{-\frac{3}{2}}|$ from his definition is definitely not a submartingale so I don't think his proof is valid.

Where do you get this exercise? If it is given as an exercise in a lecture note, then there must be some methods in that lecture note that can help you solve this problem. Otherwise, computing $E[Y_n^4]$ is just too ugly and too long. Since there is no way of splitting $Y_n$ into sum of iid r.v.s, Kolmogorov ineq is not helpful. Also, you can use some martingale methods, but I have pointed out below, it's not working. So I believe we could only rely on "raw" techniques....

I appreciate the help. This wasn't as much as an exercise but part of a research problem. I'm a physicist so I'm not very well versed in this stuff so I've taken to asking other professors and stackexchange

Following your notation, we can write
$$ Y_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n  x_i\Big) \frac{1}{n}\Big( \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i^2-1)\Big) - \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3-x_i $$
By the SLLN, the second term $\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3-x_i \rightarrow 0$ a.s., so we only need to prove the first term goes to 0. Set $Z_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n  x_i\Big) \sim N(0,1)$ and $T_n = \frac{1}{n}\Big( \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i^2-1)\Big)$, we need to prove $Z_nT_n \rightarrow 0$ a.s.. To this end, note that $Z_n \sim N(0,1) $, we use the inequality
$$ E[T_n^4Z_n^4] \leq \sqrt{E[T_n^8] E[Z_n^8]} = C_1 \sqrt{E[T_n^8]} $$
Now we need to calculate $E[T_n^8]$. At first sight, this is a whole mess but there is one nice observation the avoid the complete computation of this expectation. First, define $K_i = x_i^2 -1$, then $K_i$'s  are centered, iid r.v.s with all finite moments.
Thus, there is a universal constant $C_2$ such that
$$ E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n K_i\right)^8\right] \leq C_2n^4 $$
(Why? Hint: the highest moment $n^4$ in the expansion of this expectation corresponds to what?). So that we have
$$ E[T_n^4 Z_n^4] \leq C_1C_2 \sqrt{\frac{n^4}{n^8}}= \frac{C}{n^2} $$
and so $$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(T_nZ_n > \epsilon) \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{E[T_n^4 Z_n^4]}{\epsilon^2} \leq  \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{C}{\epsilon^2 n^2} < \infty$$
which implies $T_nZ_n \rightarrow 0$ a.s. by Borel Cantelli lemma.

@Waylander: If you get the hint, the proof is then shortened a lot. Also, since the proof only uses moments and inequalities, you can think of many ways to generalize this problem. (If this answer helps you, consider accepting it :) )

Thanks @LNT, this is very helpful and very generalizable (which I needed). I assume the hint is the fact that, the terms that have the highest scaling when you expand the power of the sum is when you match pairs so you'd always have floor{k/2} for the kth moment of the sum of iid variables.

This is my try:

Prove that $Y_n$ is a (sub)martingale

Define
$$
Z_n = Y_n \sqrt n = \frac{1}{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1\\j\neq i}^n}(x_i^2 -1) x_j
$$

Apply Doob's Inequality:
$$
P\left(max_{k \in [1,n]} Y_k \geq \frac{n^{1/4}}{\sqrt n} \right) \leq \frac{1}{n^{1/4}}E[Z_n]
$$

As $E[Z_n]$ converges, taking limits on both sides, and using that the events are nested:


$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P\left(max_{k \in [1,n]} Y_k \geq \frac{n^{1/4}}{\sqrt n} \right) = P\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} max_{k \in [1,n]} Y_k \geq 0 \right) \leq 0
$$
$$
P\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Y_n > 0 \right) \leq P\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Y_n \geq 0 \right) \leq P\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} max_{k \in [1,n]} Y_k \geq 0 \right) \leq  0
$$

Finally:

$$
P\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Y_n = 0 \right) =
1-P\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Y_n > 0 \right) \geq  1
$$
$$
\Rightarrow Y_n \rightarrow_{a.s.} 0
$$

$(Y_n)$ (from the OP's definition) is not a martingale: we already have $E[Y_n] = 0$, so if it's a submartingale, then it has to be a martingale. But this is not true, check my comments in another answer above

I believe that the proof of ${Y_N}$ being a martingale is correct...

In the other's answer, $(Y_n)$ is different from OP's definition and his proof was correct (it's a martingale, yours is the same indeed), since all expectations = 0. In your answer, Doob's inequality is wrong: In 3. it should be $E[|Y_N|] N^{1/4}$ so it doesn't help bounded the probability.
